# Cordova Android plugin callback

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Bear with me as i am beginner in Cordova framework. I want to implement a Cordova Android plugin into my mobile app such that i when i click the sharing button of the image in gallery it will help me to go to a particular view page on my app.

I am using this plugin:
https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor

I am trying to use the callback result of the plugin in JS but i am not sure how to do it. In the Android side there is this line of code that sends out the plugin result back to JS code.

```
this.listenerCallback.sendPluginResult(result);
```

The plugin JS is as follows:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
    listen: function(success, error) {
    return exec(success, error, 'SharingReceptor', 'listen', []);   
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage are described on your link: https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor

```
    cordova.SharingReceptor.listen(function(data) {
        // "data" is your payload
        // do something (success callback)
    }, function(err){
       // error callback (err is exception)
    });
```